# Delete every 30% coupon from database in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to delete every coupons with 30% discount that are in my woocommerce database. My database is default wordpress/woocommerce database (wp_)

I found [this thread](http://:%20http://www.webhat.in/article/woocommerce-tutorial/mysql-query-to-get-all-coupon/) that shows some ways to select in the database:

```
SELECT p.`ID`, 
   p.`post_title`   AS coupon_code, 
   p.`post_excerpt` AS coupon_description, 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'discount_type'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS discount_type,          -- Discount type 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'coupon_amount'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS coupon_amount,          -- Coupon amount 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'free_shipping'      AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS free_shipping,          -- Allow free shipping 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'expiry_date'        AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS expiry_date,                -- Coupon expiry date 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'minimum_amount'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS minimum_amount,         -- Minimum spend 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'maximum_amount'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS maximum_amount,         -- Maximum spend 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'individual_use'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS individual_use,         -- Individual use only 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_sale_items' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_sale_items,         -- Exclude sale items 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_ids'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS product_ids,                -- Products 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_product_ids'AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_product_ids,        -- Exclude products 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'product_categories' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS product_categories,             -- Product categories 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'exclude_product_categories' AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS exclude_product_categories,-- Exclude Product categories 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'customer_email'     AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS customer_email,         -- Email restrictions 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_limit'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit,                -- Usage limit per coupon 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_limit_per_user'   AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS usage_limit_per_user,   -- Usage limit per user 
   Max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = 'usage_count'    AND  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` THEN pm.`meta_value` END) AS total_usaged                   -- Usage count 
FROM   `wp_posts` AS p 
   INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` AS pm ON  p.`ID` = pm.`post_id` 
WHERE  p.`post_type` = 'shop_coupon' 
   AND p.`post_status` = 'publish' 
GROUP  BY p.`ID` 
ORDER  BY p.`ID` ASC;
```

But I have not yet been able to delete all 30% discount coupons.

I have 16k coupons on my database, I cant do that manually from wp-admin.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO is not a place where you simply ask other people to solve your problems without showing any work that you've attempted yourself.

Comment: i show the link that i found, i tried a lot of combinations on that link but without sucess, if you can help i will be glad and grateful!

Comment: Posting links as examples is bad form here on SO. "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Comment: right, my bad, i fixed that! Can you remove that -1 please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update 2** - Try the following SQL query from phpMyAdmin (always make a backup before):

```
DELETE a, b
FROM wp_posts AS a
JOIN wp_postmeta AS b
JOIN wp_postmeta AS c
WHERE b.post_id = a.ID AND c.post_id = a.ID
AND a.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
AND b.meta_key = 'discount_type' AND b.meta_value = 'percent'
AND c.meta_key = 'coupon_amount' AND c.meta_value = '30'
```

Tested and works.

> This query will remove all coupons data from `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables for coupons that have a 30% discount

---

Or you can run **once** the following php code that will give you the number of deleted coupons:

```
global $wpdb;
$result = $wpdb->query( "
    DELETE a, b
    FROM wp_posts AS a
    JOIN wp_postmeta AS b
    JOIN wp_postmeta AS c
    WHERE b.post_id = a.ID AND c.post_id = a.ID
    AND a.post_type = 'shop_coupon'
    AND b.meta_key = 'discount_type' AND b.meta_value = 'percent'
    AND c.meta_key = 'coupon_amount' AND c.meta_value = '30'
" );

echo '<p>Coupons deleted: ' . $result / 2  . '</p>';
```

Tested and works.

Comment: I tried with SELECT to test it, show this errors:

1.1 errors were found during the analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "FROM" at position 7)
SQL Query: Documentation

SELECT FROM wp_post AS a, wp_postmeta AS b WHERE a.ID = b.post_id AND a.post_type = 'shop_coupon' AND b.discount_type = 'percent' AND b.coupon_amount = '30'

MySQL Message: Documentation

# 1064 - You have a syntax error in your SQL next to 'FROM wp_post AS a, wp_postmeta AS b
WHERE a.ID = b.post_id AND a.post_type = 'on line 1

Comment: # 1054 - Unknown 'a' column in 'field list'

Comment: @AdrianoVarlotta I have made an update just now… it is tested and works perfectly…